# CSS3 transform complex rotation unexpected behavior

Tags: css, css-transforms

With a div viewed in perspective and having the transformations `rotateY(-90deg) rotateX(-180deg)`, prepending `rotateZ(-90deg)` does not give a rotation of -90 degrees but instead gives a rotation of +270 degrees.

The style of the div goes from
`transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateX(-180deg);`
to
`transform: rotateZ(-90deg) rotateY(-90deg) rotateX(-180deg);`

I'm not sure if this behavior is related to the fact that when you chain three rotations in the fashion `rotate(90deg) rotate(90deg) rotate(90deg)` the result is not a rotation of +270 degrees but of -90 degrees.

Please see the jsFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Sdg2W/1/

Is this a bug? Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Huh? I'm a little lost on how a rotation of "+270" or "-90" are meant to be distinguishable.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - The difference is that one rotates clockwise and the other counterclockwise. It doesn't make a difference in the end position, but it does make a difference in getting to that position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a bug that occurs on Chrome on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, it is rotating ok.
You are right when you say that one rotates clockwise, and the other counterclockwise. But you miss the fact that when rotating to +270, it rotates 3/4 of a full turn. Your fiddle does only 1/4 of a full turn.

See this other fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/vals/Sdg2W/2/]. I have changed only the way to do the transformation, so that you can play with it more easily.

I think that what is confusing you is that since there is a 180 deg in the Y axis, then the rotation is inverted (from what you would expect if that was the only transform)

Comment: Thank you for your response. It appears that this is indeed a bug. You said that my fiddle only does 1/4 of a turn, but it does 3/4 for me, on Chrome on Mac. Checking on Safari, which I should have done earlier, it rotates 1/4, as you said. This is the behavior (direction and magnitude) I expected. Hopefully the Chrome devs will fix this.

Comment: Shouldn't be difficult to fix since it's working ok on Chrome on PC :-)